# How To Check / UnCheck "Allow Numa Spanning" for Hyper-V Host Via Powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Is there a way to Check / UnCheck "Allow Numa Spanning" for Hyper-V Host Via Powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cn = 'HV1'
$NumaSpanningEnabled = $true

$vmhost = Get-WmiObject -Class Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementServiceSettingData -Namespace root\virtualization -ComputerName $cn
$vmhost.NumaSpanningEnabled=$NumaSpanningEnabled

$vmms = Get-WmiObject -Class Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService -Namespace root\virtualization -ComputerName $cn
$vmms.ModifyServiceSettings($vmhost.psbase.GetText(1))
```

In Hyper-V 3.0 it's as easy as:

```
Set-VMHost -NumaSpanningEnabled <bool>
```